# Get filtered file list from apache FileUtils

Tags: java, apache-commons, fileutils

I'm tring to get file list with specific name.
But it is not easy to use `FileterUtils` from apache commons.

My goal is getting all files with pattern `*_fact_.*`.

I tried to as below.

```
Iterator<File> picFiles = 
  FileUtils
  .iterateFiles(
     uploadFile.getParentFile(),  
     FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("*_fact_1.*"), 
     null
   );
```

But no results.

It might cause my wrong usage of `FileFilterUtils`.
What doing I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using `WildcardFileFilter` instead of `NameFileFilter`.

```
Iterator<File> picFiles = 
  FileUtils
  .iterateFiles(
     uploadFile.getParentFile(),  
     new WildcardFileFilter("*_fact_1.*"), 
     null
   );
```

Comment: Garrion  Thank you.  You saved a lot of my time.